# "errorMessage": "/var/lang/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21'

Tags: node.js, lambda

I have created a simple project in nodejs and have installed npm library to it ,url to npm is as :-
https://www.npmjs.com/package/smartethereumwallet .

Steps followed:

1. created a folder `mkdir folder_name`.
2. `npm init` -> created package.json for me.
3. `npm install --save smartethereumwallet` -> node_modules package is 
   created .
4. created `index.js` file and consoled "hello world" in it.
5. Now i have zipped this file and tried to upload on AWS lambda. selected nodejs version 6.10 and uploaded zip folder.

Getting error:

```
"errorMessage": "/var/lang/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /var/task/node_modules/scrypt/build/Release/scrypt.node)",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:597:18)",
    "Module.load (module.js:487:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)",
    "Module.require (module.js:497:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:20:19)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/scrypt/index.js:3:20)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:570:32)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:487:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)",
    "Module.require (module.js:497:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:20:19)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/scrypt.js/node.js:1:76)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:570:32)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:487:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)",
    "Module.require (module.js:497:17)"
  ]
}
```

I am using ubuntu 16.04 machine.

Comment: Please compare your question format with some other questions in the site that have had at least a few up votes and consider editing your question to look like one of them.

Comment: @yukashimahuksay - I hope it is readable now :)

Comment: It certainly is;) Good job:) and welcome to SO:D

Comment: Any luck on solving this issue? I am facing the same problem on Lambda

Comment: no solution yet found for the same . I will drop the query to npm community .